# Compare two array of objects in Joi

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

Is there a way to verify that the key that exists in one object is the same as the key that exists in the other object?

For eg:

```
{
  "localizationName": "en-US",
  "dataText": [
      {
          "persona": "gw_user",
          "verbiage": "read all patient info gw_user"
      },
      {
          "persona": "patient",
          "verbiage": "read all patient info patient"
      }
  ],
  "purposeText": [
      {
          "persona": "gw_user",
          "verbiage": "read all patient data <<purspose>> gw_user"
      },
      {
          "persona": "patient",
          "verbiage": "read all patient data <<purspose>> patient"
      }
  ]
}
```

As per the above example, the same personas exist in both "dataText" & "purposeText".

I want a joi validation code for 'whatever personas exist in the "dataText", the same personas should be defined in the "purposeText" as well'.

Below is the joi validation code I could come up with. But that doesn't seem to work.

```
    localizationName: Joi.string()
        .valid(...BCP47LanguageTags)
        .required()
        .messages({ 'any.only': '"localizationName" must be a BCP47 compliant language tag like "en-US"' }),
    dataText: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            persona: Joi.string().valid(...Persona).required(),
            verbiage: Joi.string()
        })
    ).required(),
    purposeText: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            persona: Joi.string().valid(Joi.in('dataText')).required(),
            verbiage: Joi.string()
        })
    ).required()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I am looking for some help but no luck yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function that can be used to compare properties within specified keys of a chosen object. I have also made assumptions that the properties you want to compare will be in the same order within the 2 keys.

See my code below:

```
var obj = {
  "localizationName": "en-US",
  "dataText": [
      {
          "persona": "gw_user",
          "verbiage": "read all patient info gw_user"
      },
      {
          "persona": "patient",
          "verbiage": "read all patient info patient"
      },
      {
          "persona": "test1",
          "verbiage": "added this test"
      }
  ],
  "purposeText": [
      {
          "persona": "gw_user",
          "verbiage": "read all patient data <<purspose>> gw_user"
      },
      {
          "persona": "patient",
          "verbiage": "read all patient data <<purspose>> patient"
      },
      {
          "persona": "test2",
          "verbiage": "added this test"
      }
  ]
};

function CheckPropertiesMatch(obj, keys, property){
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[keys[0]].length; i++){
    if (obj[keys[0]][i][property] == obj[keys[1]][i][property]){
        console.log("Properties at index " + i + " match!");
        } else {
        console.log("Mismatch at index " + i + "!")
    }
  }
}

CheckPropertiesMatch(obj, ['dataText',"purposeText"], "persona")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was expecting a Joi validation code to achieve this. If this is something that can't be achieved merely with joi, then I'd have to go with the manual check I guess. The order of properties need not to be in the same order.